# Error preparing the Time Machine backup disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility

One of my backup disks has problems. I keep this disk (BU2) at another location and do a backup when I'm there. The last backup was from before the upgrade to El Capitan. At home I have another backup disk (BU1), which took a very long time to complete after this backup. BU2 had to backup 130GB. After several hours only 30GB was done. It could have been only 30MB, I'm not sure anymore. I tried a second time, but no change.

I took the disk home and erased it, made a new partition, did a check. This all seemed fine. Then I linked the disk to Time Machine, checking the encryption option. I enter the password, and after clicking OK I get this message:

> There was an error preparing the Time Machine backup disk BU2.
>   Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup.

I tried this several times. Is this a problem with Time Machine, or is this disk dying? How can I do a thorough check? Disk Utitily is not what it was anymore. What is the best way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

In Disk Utility you see a master partition and when you encrypt the disk a child partition is used. Deleting en recreating this child partition didn't work, and the problem kept popping up. Erasing the master partition did the trick. So it appears that the master partition had a problem, which caused Time Machine not to work properly.

After erasing the master partition, creating an encrypted child partition, Time Machine worked and I could create a new backup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the encryption in the Time Machine Control Panel, use Disk Utility to Erase the disk, and set the Format to "Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)".

Once the partition is created and mounted, use the Time Machine Control Panel to add the new disk as a backup volume. It will automatically detect that the disk is encrypted.